# SCRIPT5039: Redeclaration of const property - IE 9 Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I have been trying to make my site cross browser compatiable.

At the moment Im having issues with my javascript IE Developer console gives me the following error:

```
SCRIPT5039: Redeclaration of const property 
banner.js, line 1 character 1
```

This is line one:

```
var linkTemplate = new Template('<b>Time/Date:</b> #{time} #{date} (GMT)<br /><b>Username:</b> <a href="profile.php?p=#{username}" target="main">#{username}</a> <br /><b>Inbox:</b> <a href="inbox.php" target="main">#{unread}/#{inbox}</a><br /><b>Money:</b> &#163;#{money}<br /><b>Location:</b> #{location}<br /><b>Bullets:</b> #{bullets}<br /><b>Kevlars:</b> #{kevlars}<br /><b>Rank:</b> #{rank} - #{rank_percent}%');
var username, hours, minutes, seconds, messages, unread, date, money, location, bullets, kevlars, rank, rank_percent, avatar, backup ;
var ps;
```

If you want to see the whole javascript:
http://www.gbmafia.com/static/js/banner.js

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS error 'redeclaration' of var when it's first line in program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578163/js-error-redeclaration-of-var-when-its-first-line-in-program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the variable `location` on line 2 is conflicting with the built-in variable `window.location`

pick another name for that variable

Comment: Fantastic, stupid of me. Sorry new to javascript. Thanks alot for your help!