# adal.js JavaScript runtime error: Redeclaration of const property on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, adal

I am using ADALjs library https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js.

When I add a reference to adal.min.js and launch the web app through IE I get the following error

**Unhandled exception at line 2, column 40 in http://localhost:16995/Scripts/adal.min.js
0x800a13af - JavaScript runtime error: Redeclaration of const property**

However if I run the same on Firefox I have no problem.  This is something specific to IE, any ideas?

Comment: which ie-version are you using?

Comment: IE 10 on Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something quite similar to this post: [JS error 'redeclaration' of var when it's first line in program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578163/js-error-redeclaration-of-var-when-its-first-line-in-program)

Also, you may need to debug into and find out the exact place where the error is thrown, I don't think IE gives the correct line and col number. The most likely reason for it is variable name conflict.